# Why is middle.next set to null?

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort

So I'm trying to sort this linked list, I understand every part of the code except this little bit, under the function `mergeSort`, line 9. 
why is `middle.next` have to be set to `null`? I don't see what this does that is necessary?

Here is a link to where I got the code from (under the java example code):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/

Here is the code:

```java
// Java program to illustrate merge sorted 
// of linkedList 

public class linkedList { 
    node head = null; 
    // node a, b; 
    static class node { 
        int val; 
        node next; 

        public node(int val) { 
            this.val = val; 
        } 
    } 

    node sortedMerge(node a, node b) { 
        node result = null; 
        /* Base cases */
        if (a == null) 
            return b; 
        if (b == null) 
            return a; 

        /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
        if (a.val <= b.val) { 
            result = a; 
            result.next = sortedMerge(a.next, b); 
        } else { 
            result = b; 
            result.next = sortedMerge(a, b.next); 
        } 
        return result; 
    } 

    node mergeSort(node h) { 
        // Base case : if head is null 
        if (h == null || h.next == null) { 
            return h; 
        } 

        // get the middle of the list 
        node middle = getMiddle(h); 
        node nextofmiddle = middle.next; 

        // set the next of middle node to null 
        middle.next = null; 

        // Apply mergeSort on left list 
        node left = mergeSort(h); 

        // Apply mergeSort on right list 
        node right = mergeSort(nextofmiddle); 

        // Merge the left and right lists 
        node sortedlist = sortedMerge(left, right); 
        return sortedlist; 
    } 

    // Utility function to get the middle of the linked list 
    node getMiddle(node h) { 
        // Base case 
        if (h == null) 
            return h; 
        node fastptr = h.next; 
        node slowptr = h; 

        // Move fastptr by two and slow ptr by one 
        // Finally slowptr will point to middle node 
        while (fastptr != null) { 
            fastptr = fastptr.next; 
            if (fastptr != null) { 
                slowptr = slowptr.next; 
                fastptr = fastptr.next; 
            } 
        } 
        return slowptr; 
    } 

    void push(int new_data) { 
        /* allocate node */
        node new_node = new node(new_data); 

        /* link the old list off the new node */
        new_node.next = head; 

        /* move the head to point to the new node */
        head = new_node; 
    } 

    // Utility function to print the linked list 
    void printList(node headref) { 
        while (headref != null) { 
            System.out.print(headref.val + " "); 
            headref = headref.next; 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        linkedList li = new linkedList(); 
        /* 
         * Let us create a unsorted linked list to test the functions 
         * created. The list shall be a: 2->3->20->5->10->15 
         */
        li.push(15); 
        li.push(10); 
        li.push(5); 
        li.push(20); 
        li.push(3); 
        li.push(2); 

        // Apply merge Sort 
        li.head = li.mergeSort(li.head); 
        System.out.print("\n Sorted Linked List is: \n"); 
        li.printList(li.head); 
    } 
} 

// This code is contributed by Rishabh Mahrsee
```

Comment: Sounds like it's breaking the list into two smaller lists, so it can recursively call itself

Comment: Note that a [bottom up iterative merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) eliminates the need for scanning to split lists. Instead it uses a small (26 to 32) array of pointers or references to nodes.

Comment: @AlanKamali: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

`mergeSort` sets the `next` member of the middle node to `null` to split the list `h` into 2 separate lists `h` and `nextofmiddle` which it sorts by calling itself recursively and then merges to produce `sortedList`.

Note however that this code has a major problem: the method `sortedMerge` is also recursive with a stack depth of the combined length of both lists, potentially a large number. This recursion cannot be easily simplified by the compiler as a tail recursion, hence sorting long lists with this code will likely crash.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `middle.next = null` is to break the list into two parts. The value after the last node in a linked list should always be NULL, so that is why the author set the `next` node of the `middle` node to a NULL value. The author is creating one sublist containing nodes from `head` to `middle` and a second sublist containing nodes from `nextofmiddle` to end of list. Each time this function is called, the sublist is broken into smaller parts, which is part of the merge sort process.

Answer (score 0):

So if you see the whole code, `mergeSort()` is called recursively,

```
 // Apply mergeSort on left list 
    node left = mergeSort(h); 

 // Apply mergeSort on right list 
    node right = mergeSort(nextofmiddle);
```

And by putting `middle.next = null`, it is actually breaking the recursion of the calling method in the method stack. So it will return the current node when we recursively call the same method,

```
if (h == null || h.next == null) { 
    return h; 
}
```

So if you see the psedo code,

```
MergeSort(headRef)
1) If the head is NULL or there is only one element in the Linked List 
   then return.
2) Else divide the linked list into two halves.  
   FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b); /* a and b are two halves */
3) Sort the two halves a and b.
    MergeSort(a);
    MergeSort(b);
4) Merge the sorted a and b (using SortedMerge() discussed here) 
   and update the head pointer using headRef.
   *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b);
```

Its effectively breaking the list in 2 halves and individually MergeSort them by calling the same method. To achieve the same it is first copy the next value in `nextofmiddle` and them making the `middle.next = null;` to break the recursion loop.

I hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the author is looking for the middle point of the list in the method `node getMiddle(node h)`. This returns the middle node, but you want to break the list into two parts, a left hand side and a right hand side.

Setting `middle.next = null` splits the list into the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

It's to split the list in two: when the middle element is found, the first part will end at the middle element, so `middle.next` is set to null. The previous value of `middle.next` is the beginning if the second part.